# Is it possible to do parallel writes on one h5py file using multiprocessing?

Tags: python-2.7, io, python-multiprocessing, h5py

I wrote a simple program that would see if I could naively fill an hdf5 file with dummy data.

```
import sys                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
import multiprocessing as mp                                                                                                                                                                                                      
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                                                
import h5py                                                                                                                                                                                                                       


def parallel_h5write(hdf, key, data):                                                                                                                                                                                             
    dset = hdf.create_dataset(key, shape=data.shape, dtype=data.dtype)                                                                                                                                                            
    dset[:] = data                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    hdf.flush()                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    return None                                                                                                                                                                                                                   


large_data = np.array([                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    float(j)*np.ones(20000) for j in xrange(1, 20001)                                                                                                                                                                             
])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                


start = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                                               
h5file = h5py.File('serial.h5', 'w')                                                                                                                                                                                              
for j, data in enumerate(large_data):                                                                                                                                                                                             
    nm = "name{0}".format(j)                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    dset = h5file.create_dataset(nm, shape=data.shape, dtype=data.dtype)                                                                                                                                                          
    dset[:] = data                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    h5file.flush()                                                                                                                                                                                                                
h5file.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
finish = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                                              
print "serial write took {0} seconds".format(finish - start)                                                                                                                                                                      
start = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                                               


h5file = h5py.File('parallel.h5', 'w')                                                                                                                                                                                            
arglist = [(h5file, 'name{0}'.format(j), data) for j, data in enumerate(large_data)]                                                                                                                                              
p = mp.Pool(4)                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
try:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    p.map(parallel_h5write, arglist)                                                                                                                                                                                              
except Exception, err:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    p.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    p.join()                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    print err                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    sys.exit()                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
p.close()                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
p.join()                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
finish = time.time()                                                                                                                                                                                                              
print "parallel write took {0} seconds".format(finish - start)
```

I got the following error message:

```
Exception KeyError: KeyError(0,) in 'h5py._objects.ObjectID.__dealloc__' ignored
Process PoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 267, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 102, in worker
    task = get()
  File "/home/user/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 376, in get
    return recv()
  File "stringsource", line 5, in h5py.h5f.__pyx_unpickle_FileID
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 178, in h5py._objects.ObjectID.__cinit__
TypeError: __cinit__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (0 given)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h5py/_objects.pyx", line 200, in h5py._objects.ObjectID.__dealloc__
KeyError: 0
```

Needless to say I am not sure what to do with this error message. What am I doing wrong? What could I do to fix this? Can I actually do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do parallel i/o with HDF5. It is supported natively with the HDF API (don't use `multiprocessing` module). Instead it uses `mpi4py` module. The setup is explained in the h5py documentation. Look [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html) --`Parallel HDF5`.

Comment: I see. I was just wondering if it were possible with multiprocessing as I am running this code on a supercomputer. And I think it would be difficult to get the mpi4py module on it. But I suppose the time I would save in I/O would make the trouble worth it.