# How to compress existing h5py file efficiently using multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, hdf5, h5py

I have a program that streams large amounts of data I need to save for later processing. This program is highly time sensitive, and as such I need to save the data as quickly as possible. To handle large volumes of data, I use `h5py` and do not use compression to ensure we take as little time as possible to save the data. My program looks something like this:

```py
# Open the h5py for writing
hf = h5py.File('raw_data.hdf5', 'w')

# Simulates getting 100 sets of data from my application
for i in tqdm(range(100)):
    # Simulates getting the data
    data = np.random.random(size = (500, 500, 500))

    # Save to h5py using no compression to minimize write time
    hf.create_dataset('{0:03d}'.format(i), data=data)

# Close the h5py file
hf.close()
```

Running this on my computer takes `~0.9` seconds and creates a `~600MB` file (my actual program generates loops over many more iterations and creates much larger files). To avoid wasting space, after collecting the data, I re-compress the file using:

```py
# Open the raw data file and create a new output compressed file
hf_in = h5py.File('raw_data.hdf5', 'r')
hf_out = h5py.File('compressed_data.hdf5', 'w')

# Simulates getting 100 sets of data from my application
for key in tqdm(hf_in.keys()):
    # Load data
    data = hf_in.get(key)
    # Save compressed data
    hf_out.create_dataset('{}'.format(key), data=data, compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)

# Close the h5py file
hf_in.close()
hf_out.close()
```

This example takes `~15` seconds (i.e., 15X longer than my streaming program). **Note:** In this example, the file size won't be reduced significantly, but that's because we are feeding it random data. My actual program gets `~10X` size reductions, which I need.

I noticed that the compression only uses a single core and hoped to speed it up using `multiprocessing`. I read that we can use command line tools to do the compression in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903867/compression-of-existing-file-using-h5py). However, I hope to avoid that, as I want to fully automate this process in my python script.

My question is: Is it possible to use multiprocessing to do multiple reads from the original `hdf5` file, compress the data, and save it back to a new compressed `hdf5` file. An example of this would look something like:

```py
def write_back_compressed(key):
    global h5_in, h5_out
    # Load the data
    data = h5_in[key]
    # Write the data to the file
    h5_out.create_dataset(key, data=data, compression="gzip", compression_opts=9)
    return None

# Load the file
global h5_in, h5_out
hf_in = h5py.File('raw_data.hdf5', 'r')
hf_out = h5py.File('compressed_parallel_data.hdf5', 'w')

# Create a number of processors
total_processors = int(4)
pool =  multiprocessing.Pool(processes=total_processors)

# Call our function total_test_suites times
jobs = []
for key in hf_in.keys():
    # Write it back compressed
    jobs.append(pool.apply_async(write_back_compressed, args=([key])))

# Get the results
for job in tqdm(jobs):
    job.get()

# Close the pool
pool.close()
hf_in.close()
```

However, when I run this, I get an error stating that it can't lock the file for writing: `OSError: [Errno 0] Unable to create file (unable to lock file, errno = 0, error message = 'No error', Win32 GetLastError() = 33)`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54546499/is-it-possible-to-do-parallel-writes-on-one-h5py-file-using-multiprocessing) suggests I can do this with `mpi4py` however I can't get that working either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yeah, you need MPI. That's the only parallelization [properly supported](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html). What error do you get with mpi4py and what code did you try with it?

Comment: You can _**read HDF5 files in parallel**_ with h5py as-is. However, to _**write HDF5 files in parallel**_ both HDF5 and h5py must be compiled with MPI support turned on. Have you done that? The steps are described here: [Parallel HDF5](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/mpi.html)

Comment: if your data is highly compressible, you can go much faster on a single thread with `compression_opts=1`, and you'll probably still get decent compression ratio.

Comment: With all these complications, it seems that if you want to do parallelization it might just be best not to use h5py?

Comment: The trouble isn't with h5py but with the main HDF5 library. Since there are no competing implementations you have to say goodbye to the entire data format. Or use transparent compression on the file system / wrap the whole file with a parallelized compressor.

Comment: That's sad :( I was so hopeful, as this library seemed to solve so many of my previous issues with writing thousands of text or CSV files...